# MVC 4 SEO Multilanguage domain based

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, seo

Well I am confused with the SEO part

I develop a Multilanguage site on MVC 4 with two options.
Multilanguage is based on a cookie and recourses file changing the culture of the site. Options are en, el. On each top level domain site has always Greek and English option no redirects between domains.

The site urls are (example)
site1Products.gr
site1Products.com

Now I want the site1Products.gr to be index from Google with the Greek content and 
site1Products.com  be index with the English content.

So if I set

1) the default value of the cookie for .gr domain to el and for .com domain to en

2) On web config   for .gr domain   and     for .com domain

Would Google index the correct content for each domain?
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know keeping content on separate urls is better and google will know how to index it automatically, but you need to localize all elements from your page ( menus, titles, headers and so on )

Please follow this link for more info : [How google indexes multilingual web apps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1)